# Somehow a row is inserted twice even only one flush() exists;

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I made simple search form with the search query log.

in my indexAction

```
public function indexAction(){

    $searchLog = new SearchLog;

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($searchLog)
    ->add('query','text')
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Search'))
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('acme_top_searchResult'))
    ->getForm();
```

'acme_top_searchResult' invokes the searchResultAction();
I receive the query in my searchResultAction

```
public function searchResultAction(Request $request){
    //var_dump($request);
    $searchLog = new SearchLog;
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($searchLog)
    ->add('query')
    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $queryData = $form->getData();
    $this->em->persist($searchLog);
    $this->em->flush();

    $sq = $queryData->getQuery(); // use $sq for searching
```

However it inserted two rows in database. why is it happens??

---

I tried this.

```
public function searchResultAction(Request $request){

    $searchLog = new SearchLog();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($searchLog)
    ->add('query')
    ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()){// however it dose not return true
```

however $form->isValid() does not return true

I paste the var_dump($request) log below.

it lookes like submit has done well......
Could anyone help me ???

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)[3]
  public 'attributes' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)[6]
      protected 'parameters' => 
        array (size=3)
          '_controller' => string 'Acme\TopBundle\Controller\DefaultController::searchResultAction' (length=63)
          '_route' => string 'acme_top_searchResult' (length=21)
          '_route_params' => 
            array (size=0)
              empty
  public 'request' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)[4]
      protected 'parameters' => 
        array (size=1)
          'form' => 
            array (size=3)
              'query' => string 'rarara' (length=6)
              'save' => string '' (length=0)
              '_token' => string 'QUF1ZJU3EVTvnC3LKfdQR2z_-OuQnG2FTDs8vrTGucs' (length=43)
  public 'query' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)[5]
      protected 'parameters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  public 'server' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag)[9]myApp
      protected 'parameters' => 
        array (size=37)
          'HTTP_HOST' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
          'CONTENT_LENGTH' => string '99' (length=2)
          'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => string 'max-age=0' (length=9)
          'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' (length=74)
          'HTTP_ORIGIN' => string 'http://localhost' (length=16)
          'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36' (length=121)
          'CONTENT_TYPE' => string 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' (length=33)
          'HTTP_REFERER' => string 'http://localhost/myApp/web/app_dev.php/' (length=43)
          'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip, deflate' (length=13)
          'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' (length=23)
          'HTTP_COOKIE' => string 'PHPSESSID=iqpa901b7sfurcs9kvlkis3v52' (length=36)
          'PATH' => string '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' (length=29)
          'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => string '' (length=0)
          'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.6.9' (length=29)
          'SERVER_NAME' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          'SERVER_ADDR' => string '::1' (length=3)
          'SERVER_PORT' => string '80' (length=2)
          'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '::1' (length=3)
          'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string '/Users/MyName/CodingWorks/httproot' (length=34)
          'REQUEST_SCHEME' => string 'http' (length=4)
          'CONTEXT_PREFIX' => string '' (length=0)
          'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string '/Users/MyName/CodingWorks/httproot' (length=34)
          'SERVER_ADMIN' => string 'you@example.com' (length=15)
          'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string '/Users/MyName/CodingWorks/httproot/myApp/web/app_dev.php' (length=60)
          'REMOTE_PORT' => string '51319' (length=5)
          'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => string 'CGI/1.1' (length=7)
          'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.1' (length=8)
          'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'POST' (length=4)
          'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
          'REQUEST_URI' => string '/myApp/web/app_dev.php/sr' (length=29)
          'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/myApp/web/app_dev.php' (length=26)
          'PATH_INFO' => string '/sr' (length=3)
          'PATH_TRANSLATED' => string '/Users/MyName/CodingWorks/httproot/sr' (length=37)
          'PHP_SELF' => string '/myApp/web/app_dev.php/sr' (length=29)
          'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => float 1436891356.666
          'REQUEST_TIME' => int 1436891356
  public 'files' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)[8]
      protected 'parameters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  public 'cookies' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)[7]
      protected 'parameters' => 
        array (size=1)
          'PHPSESSID' => string 'iqpa901b7sfurcs9kvlkis3v52' (length=26)
  public 'headers' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag)[10]
      protected 'headers' => 
        array (size=13)
          'host' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          'connection' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
          'content-length' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '99' (length=2)
          'cache-control' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'max-age=0' (length=9)
          'accept' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' (length=74)
          'origin' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'http://localhost' (length=16)
          'user-agent' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36' (length=121)
          'content-type' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' (length=33)
          'referer' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'http://localhost/myApp/web/app_dev.php/' (length=43)
          'accept-encoding' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'gzip, deflate' (length=13)
          'accept-language' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' (length=23)
          'cookie' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string 'PHPSESSID=iqpa901b7sfurcs9kvlkis3v52' (length=36)
          'x-php-ob-level' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => int 1
      protected 'cacheControl' => 
        array (size=1)
          'max-age' => string '0' (length=1)
  protected 'content' => null
  protected 'languages' => null
  protected 'charsets' => null
  protected 'encodings' => null
  protected 'acceptableContentTypes' => null
  protected 'pathInfo' => string '/sr' (length=3)
  protected 'requestUri' => string '/myApp/web/app_dev.php/sr' (length=29)
  protected 'baseUrl' => string '/myApp/web/app_dev.php' (length=26)
  protected 'basePath' => null
  protected 'method' => string 'POST' (length=4)
  protected 'format' => null
  protected 'session' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session)[58]
      protected 'storage' => 
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage)[57]
          protected 'bags' => 
            array (size=2)
              'attributes' => 
                object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag)[435]
                  private 'name' => string 'attributes' (length=10)
                  private 'storageKey' => string '_sf2_attributes' (length=15)
                  protected 'attributes' => &
                    array (size=5)
                      '_csrf/form' => string 'QUF1ZJU3EVTvnC3LKfdQR2z_-OuQnG2FTDs8vrTGucs' (length=43)
                      '_locale' => string 'en' (length=2)
                      '_csrf/authenticate' => string 'ojhFU-vZUjlbBmAyza7fKnYsd_Oam_M1e35W_-qJkHE' (length=43)
                      '_security_main' => string 'C:68:"HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\OAuthToken":1098:{a:7:{i:0;s:218:"CAAFDj1Jc7IABAEpHpntZBDjZAIb74QGEsL5K0CEWWvGHNfnk7kGrYTzN9ssMfa6PasjIMsuDXhHlulqSxXeRLLrkxTPAaxu7ygoMeGlahUjK6UDB8nRCtHhtkJdlWxpgSFy3ESeGW9dPgbZAWisEdR5xiTnwaB6B6xk4EGxlOQ8vMZCZBeBJ4ZBJ5rghCpeZCseLUF6ZAAzSvk7rZBisDHg7j";i:1;a:2:{s:12:"access_token";s:218:"CAAFDj1Jc7IABAEpHpntZBDjZAIb74QGEsL5K0CEWWvGHNfnk7kGrYTzN9ssMfa6PasjIMsuDXhHlulqSxXeRLLrkxTPAaxu7ygoMeGlahUjK6UDB8nRCtHhtkJdlWxpgSFy3ESeGW9dPgbZAWisEdR5xiTnwaB6B6xk4EGxlOQ8vMZCZBeBJ4ZBJ5rghCpeZCseLUF6ZAAzSvk7rZBisDHg7j";s:7:"expires";s:7:"5150639";}i:2;N;i:3;s:7:"5150639";i:4;i:1436891127;i:5;s:8:"facebook";i:6;s:503:"a:4:{i:0;C:27:"Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User":166:{a:9:{i:0;s:8:"ZKkyZy84";i:1;s:31:"2bhrsabaoh7okoc8cc8cg0o4swccc0c";i:2;s:17:"10201664509493403";i:3;s:17:"10201664509493403";i:4;b:0;i:5;b:0;i:6;b:0;i:7;b:1;i:8;i:1;}}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:2:{i:0;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"�Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role�role";s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}i:1;O:41:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":1:{s:47:"�Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role�role";s:9:"ROLE_USER";}}i:3;a:0:{}}";}}' (length=1181)
                      '_csrf/sonata.batch' => string 't0FJ67l9S_2fn1YA-zlspeorTBvr0f7FRyZSjBJedFs' (length=43)
              'flashes' => 
                object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag)[436]
                  private 'name' => string 'flashes' (length=7)
                  private 'flashes' => &
                    array (size=0)
                      empty
                  private 'storageKey' => string '_sf2_flashes' (length=12)
          protected 'started' => boolean true
          protected 'closed' => boolean false
          protected 'saveHandler' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy)[432]
              protected 'handler' => 
                object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler)[56]
              protected 'wrapper' => boolean true
              protected 'active' => boolean true
              protected 'saveHandlerName' => string 'files' (length=5)
          protected 'metadataBag' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MetadataBag)[55]
              private 'name' => string '__metadata' (length=10)
              private 'storageKey' => string '_sf2_meta' (length=9)
              protected 'meta' => &
                array (size=3)
                  'u' => int 1436891357
                  'c' => int 1436891127
                  'l' => string '0' (length=1)
              private 'lastUsed' => int 1436891143
              private 'updateThreshold' => string '0' (length=1)
      private 'flashName' => string 'flashes' (length=7)
      private 'attributeName' => string 'attributes' (length=10)
  protected 'locale' => string 'en' (length=2)
  protected 'defaultLocale' => string 'en' (length=2)
```

Comment: perhaps you should place a check if the form is submitted only do the persist stuff

Comment: Thanks I have done some test and update articles. I really appreciate if you check this.

Comment: It is sloved, the reason is I don't add the ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Search')) to the formbuilder in searchResultAction. var_dump($form->getErrors()); could be quite big help.